# Spring Boot Apache Kafka + REST API GET

Tags: rest, apache-kafka

I'm building an app that must be abble to consume Kafka messages from a rest API GET.
What I mean is that I want to expose a rest API GET, that can be able to consume Kafka message from the begening.
I saw that some tutorials talk about publishing through a rest webservice but not consuming from a rest web service.
Is there any way to consume message synchroniously from Kafka ?
Cordially.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. But there's no reason to reinvent the wheel. Confluent REST Proxy or Strimzi's Kafka Bridge are already capable tools for this.

Otherwise, use Kafka Connect to dump data into a database. Use Spring Data behind a REST API, instead. This would allow you to re-query and filter the data rather than messing with Kafka partition and offsets, as well as aggregate data over several topics